# Do I need to wait for Sent/Failure event for each message with PushSharp

Tags: c#, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I can send `APNS` notifications with `PushSharp` but I need to be able to send messages to multiple devices and I cannot find any more information on `PushSharp` and have some questions:

1. Should I wait for the `OnNotificationSent` / `OnNotificationSendFailure` events to fire before I send my next message?
2. How do I uniquely identify a message in the `OnNotificationSent` / `OnNotificationSendFailureevent`?
3. If I queue multiple messages will the `OnNotificationSent` / `OnNotificationSendFailureevent` fire for all of them?

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldnt wait for response before you send the next message.
   send all of them without waiting.
2. Then you should be able to uniquely identify the message. The Notification object
   has a Tag property. You can set its value and get it in the OnNotificationSent/
   OnNotificationSendFailure event handlers.
3. Yes. these methods should fire for all the messages